# Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 2 - Scheduled Backups Wizard

Tags: backup

After applying Update 2 - the *Scheduled Backup* is now a build-in feature (not requiring Power Tool). I have difficult understanding the required permissions required to dump a backup on a file-share. Even when trying to dump the backup on a local share - \mytfs2012server\c$\Backup - the wizard ends up with a:

```
TF401002: The SQL Server Database Engine failed to save the database backup to path... Please grant SQL service account read/write access to that folder.
```

The message is very simple. I have tried different things - without success. With Update 1 + Power Tools I succeeded to use the wizard after some tweaking. Anyone that can list the permissions required for the *Scheduled Backup* for Update 2?

**Edit:**

Update 3 did not change anything for me. However it looks like Update 4 will. From [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872520) it looks like Update 4 will include changes regarding backup:

- Scheduled Backups configuration is no longer blocked if the SQL Server service for TFS 2012 is running as a virtual account (for example: NT Service\MSSQLSERVER).
  In TFS 2012 Update 2 and Update 3, transactional backups record a failure when they try to run while a full or differential backup is running.
- Scheduled Backups no longer run transactional backups if a full or differential backup is running. Instead, the job will be suspended until the other backup has finished running.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem.

Infrastuctur: TFS 2012 Update 2, SQL Server 2012

Solution:
I created a simple shared Folder like \BACKUPSERVER\TFS_Backup$ on the DB Backup Server. 
I configured the **TFS admin** and the **SQL Admin** with Full Control in the **Security** and **Share Permissions**.
Now the Backup Job is running.

But now i have an other Problem:
After running a Full Backup the Transaction-Logs were not truncated, does any one have the same Problem or maybe an solution?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using virtual accounts for the server? Something like 'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER'?  If so be aware that they aren't supported in the Scheduled Backups Wizard in both TFS 2012.2 & 2012.3.

You either have to create the backup plans manually or switch the SQL service account to a domain account or Network Service.

EDIT:

As per the comments, TFS 2012.4 RC2 and up has removed this restriction

Comment: Not sure if there is a change in Update 3. From here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600: An error message incorrectly displays the MSSQL Server account instead of the Job Agent account when you configure scheduled backups.

Comment: Update 4 RC2 removes the virtual account restriction.  From here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872520: Scheduled Backups configuration is no longer blocked if the SQL Server service for TFS 2012 is running as a virtual account (for example: NT Service\MSSQLSERVER).